# Working with incremented variable in a funciton not working

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I'm new to python and trying to solve some problems with it. I'm trying to increment a variable and then using that incremented variable in a function but it looks like it's not using the incremented variable.

So this is my code:

```
var = 0
line_num = 0 + var

def incerement_problem(line_number):
    if line_number == 1:
        print("true")
    else:
        global var
        var += 1

incerement_problem(line_num)
incerement_problem(line_num)
```

So after the second function call the code should give me back the "true" message, but instead of that it just increments the variable and looks like it's using the original value which is 0.

What I see is that the var variable is incrementing properly. But line_num variable stays 0.

I don't understand what is the problem hope somebody can explain it to me.

Comment: you need to increment `line_num` not `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to increment `line_num` not `var`

```
line_num = 0

def incerement_problem(line_number):
    if line_number == 1:
        print("true")
    else:
        global line_num
        line_num+=1

incerement_problem(line_num)
incerement_problem(line_num)
```

Output:

```
true
```

Update:

```
line_num = 0
var = 0

def incerement_problem(line_number):
    if line_number == 1:
        print("true")
    else:
        global line_num
        global var
        var = 1
        line_num+=var

incerement_problem(line_num)
incerement_problem(line_num)
```

Comment: Yes this could be a solution but I need to make it work with the way I wrote in the example. So i need to add a variable value to another variable and then use that in the function. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks it is working! Can you explain to me why it is working with the edit you did?

Comment: I don't recommend using `global`. in the second approach, I'm incrementing both variables and adding. So, it incremented both the values

Comment: Yes I see that but why it isn't working when I only adding the incremented var variable to line_num? After incrementing var the line_num still shows me 0 when I print out line_num (when I working with my example).